# How to prove that $S^1 \times S^3$ identifying antipodal points is again $S^1 \times S^3$.

Tags: general-topology, general-relativity, compactification

I am studying the compactification of Minkowski spacetime as the space of generators $\mathcal{PN}$ of the null cone $\mathcal{N}$ of a six dimensional real manifold of signature 2. Concretely I am following the book "An introduction to twistor theory" by Huggett and Tod
[(see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0JRU.png). Topologically the say that $\mathcal{PN}$ is $S^1\times S^3$ identifying antipodal points (because each generator cuts the 5-sphere twice), which is again $S^1\times S^3$. Does anybody know why $S^1\times S^3/\sim$ is again $S^1\times S^3$?

And can this be extended to $S^1\times S^n$ in general?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of $PN$? The original definition does not seem to be $S^1 \times S^3/\sim $,  but the space of generators of $N$.

Comment: You could find a map $f:S^1\times S^3\to S^1\times S^3$ constant on the fibers of the projections $\pi$, where $\pi:S^1\times S^3\to S^1\times S^3/\sim$.

Answer (score 6):

$S^1$ and $S^3$ can be identified with the unit spheres in $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C^2$ respectively.  Then the map $$(z, w) \mapsto (z^2, z w)$$ where $z \in \mathbb C$, $w \in \mathbb C^2$ and $\lvert z \rvert = \lVert w \rVert = 1$ identifies exactly the antipodal points.

Comment: And can this argument be extended to $S^1\times S^n$?? Because I don't think so but the compactification must hold...

Comment: For odd $n$ the argument is the same. For even $n$ I think the quotient is not orientable, while the product of spheres is.